# RSpec 2: NoMethodError on 'route_to' with rspec-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, rspec-rails

I'm trying to run this test...

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe HomeController do

  describe 'boilerplate routes' do

    it "should route to '/about'" do
      { :get => "/about" }.should route_to(:controller => 'home', :action => 'show')
    end

  end

end
```

... and it keeps failing with this error message:

```
1) HomeController boilerplate routes should route to '/about'
Failure/Error: { :get => "/about" }.should route_to(:controller => 'home', :action => 'show')
   NoMethodError:
      undefined method `route_to' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x00000101499650>
   # ./spec/routes/home_routes_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm using `rspec-rails 2.5.0` with `rails 3.0.5` & `rspec 2.5.1`.

I'm doing my code just like it says in the [rdocs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/2.5.0/frames), trying to follow along with [this example code](https://github.com/wolframarnold/Efficient-Test-Driven-Rails-Development/blob/master/spec/routing/people_controller_routing_spec.rb)... what am I doing wrong? Help!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Aph, found my problem.

I had my routing spec folder named `spec/routes` instead of `spec/routing`, which it should be.

Missed that in the [readme](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails).

Comment: I did the same thing by renaming my file so TextMate's RSpec bundle could jump between routes.rb and routes_spec.rb... d'oh!

Comment: This solution is still valid as of Rails 4.2 and rspec-rails 3.2.1.

Comment: I'm am in the process of upgrading from Rails 4.0 to Rails 4.2, and I'm still getting the same error. Any other thoughts?